# Probability of choosing same coloured balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are five red balls and five green balls in a bag. Two balls are taken out at random. What is the probability that both the balls are of the same colour

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts in 
this and future posts. Formatting tips 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint:  Another way of asking the question is what is the probability that the second ball is the same colour as the first?

Comment: @Achari, you have accepeted answer only $4$ out of your $65$ question?  https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Achari, people are helping you, please show your work/comment below answers if you are satisfied then accept your answer any. This is part of asking a question. You will be receive reputation and vote-up.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If you have taken one ball out then in the bag there are $4$ balls that have the color of the drawn ball and $5$ that have *not* the color of the drawn ball.

Answer (score 2):

The number of ways to choose $2$ balls is $\binom{5+5}{2}=45$.

The number of ways to choose $2$ red balls is $\binom{5}{2}=10$.

The number of ways to choose $2$ green balls is $\binom{5}{2}=10$.

Hence the probability of choosing $2$ balls of the same color is $\frac{10+10}{45}=\frac49$.

Comment: But why addition 10+10

Comment: @AchariSGanesha: The event of choosing $2$ red balls and the event of choosing $2$ green balls are **disjoint events**, so you can simply add their probabilities.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that you are interested in the event $GG$ or $RR$.
Let's consider the $GG$ case. The probability that you get first $G$
is $$\frac{5}{10}.$$ Then there are $4$ $G$ left and a total of $9$ total. Now, in the second draw, what is the probability that you get another $G$? That is
$$\frac{4}{9}.$$
Thus the probability of $GG$ is
$$\frac{5}{10}\cdot\frac{4}{9} = \frac{20}{90}.$$
Notice that this is the same probability as $RR$. Thus, the probability of same color twice is
$$2\times\frac{20}{90} = \frac{20}{45} = \frac{4}{9}.$$

Comment: @AchariSGanesha Because in the first step you draw a $G$. In the second step, there are 4 $G$ ball left in the bag with 9 balls total. So it's first step $\times$ second step$\implies \frac{5}{10}\frac{4}{9} = \frac{20}{90}.$

Answer (score 1):

Using [Hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution): Given, $5$ red and $5$ green ball. So, total number balls is $10$.

Two balls are taken at random, So required probability is :

$= \frac{^5C_2 \times ^5C_0 + ^5C_2 \times ^5C_0}{^{10}C_2}=\frac{10+10}{45}=\frac{20}{45}$